# how to improve scan performance in hbase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am using hbase96 for analytic purpose. I am fetching data from hbase by applying single column value filters on the range of row keys by defining startRow and endRow.

It is taking 5-6 minutes for scanning 1500000 records for single request.It is not handling concurrent requests.
How can I improve performance of scanning in hbase?

We have 3 datanodes and 2 master nodes on amazone.

below is my code

```
Scan s = new Scan();
s.setCaching(10000);

s.setStartRow(Bytes.toBytes(start_date));
s.setStopRow(Bytes.toBytes(end_date));

FilterList filters = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);

SingleColumnValueFilter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
Bytes.toBytes("log"), Bytes.toBytes("ad_id"),
CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(ad_id));
filters.addFilter(filter);

SingleColumnValueFilter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
Bytes.toBytes("log"), Bytes.toBytes("advertiser_id"),
CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(adver_id));
filters.addFilter(filter);

s.setFilter(filters);

ResultScanner rs = click_table.getScanner(s);
```

How above code can be used in coproccessor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to scan based on Column values
then below are best ways

1. Solr (CDH Search) https://wiki.apache.org/solr/
2. Hindex (coprocessor based   approach)https://communities.intel.com/community/itpeernetwork/datastack/blog/2013/10/30/coprocessor-based-secondary-index-on-hbase

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `scan.setCaching(100000)` while performing queries. It specifies the number of rows that will be transmitted per RPC to the regionserver.

**Edit:** Also, try setting `batch and buffer sizes` depending on your network bandwidth.
Each application has different structure and require different tuning parameters.. try to tweak these values for your data.

If performance is still the same.. try using parallel fetching of data. [This](https://www.ericsson.com/en/blog/2013/1/hbase-performance-tuners) might help.

HTH

Comment: I am new to HBase. It would be great if could tell me how to use coprocessor.

Comment: [This](https://blogs.apache.org/hbase/entry/coprocessor_introduction) might help you in understanding coprocessors, how to build them.. and deploy to your cluster.

Comment: I have edited my question by adding some line of code that am using. I read about coprocessors, and I don't want to do any computation in that. I need whole data in response. As you can see in the code that I have used filters. By using coprocessors, how the preformance can be improved ?